# Maintain Image Size on Screen Rotation

Tags: android

I am developing an application that'll show the image and some text below it to a user after launching a frame inside an activity. 
I'm assigning the `drawable` resource to `ImageView` programmatically.

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avaImage);
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ava_green));
```

So far so good. But when I rotate the screen of the device, Android changes the resolution of the image. I want it to be remained as-is. How can I achieve that?
This is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 tools:context=".NavigationActivity"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avaImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/txtLabel"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you triend setRetainInstance(true) on the fragment and adding android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" in Maninfest.xml to stop the activity from resetting on rotation?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to stop the activity from resetting on rotation. I just have to maintain an image size in one of the many fragments I'm using in my app